# Как вырезать два небольших сегмента из окружности и вращать их при наведении курсора

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

На многих сайтах стали появляться эффекты вращения окружностей с симметрично вырезанными небольшими участками. [Смотрится хорошо](https://www.airforce.com/chat-live). Как повторить данный эффект?

У меня получилось вырезать один сегмент с помощью атрибутов `stroke-dasharray`

Ниже код:

```css
.txt1  {fill:white; pointer-events:none;}
.rect {fill:gray;}
.txt1:hover {fill:white;}
.rect:hover {fill:black; transition:fill 0.5s all;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="320" height="60" viewBox="0 0 350 60" >   
   <g id="gr1" >
    
   <rect class="rect"  x="62" y="11" rx="10" width="250" height="40" />
       <text class="txt1" x="75" y="40" font-size="22" > SPECIAL OPERATIONS </text>
 <circle id="crc1" cx="30" cy="30" r="20"   stroke='grey' stroke-width="3" fill='transparent' 
        stroke-dasharray="115.66 10"  stroke-dashoffset="-35.41" >
    </circle>  
  </g>
</svg>
```

Как вырезать второй симметричный сегмент и заставить их вращаться при наведении на надпись?

**Update**

Добавлен новый ответ:

[вариант - только HTML и CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/943867/28748) @UModeL

### Дополнительные условия для конкурса:

Было бы очень интересно получить ответы с решением `CSS`, `JS` реализующие анимации, как в ответе [анимации с SVG](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/944006/28748)

- Вращение одного сегмента
- Техника создания анимаций фигур с количеством сегментов больше двух
- Анимация симметричного заполнения фигур из одной точки

Предпочтения в выборе победителя при равенстве решений, будут отданы ответу с хорошо комментированным кодом.

**Ответы с применением плагинов, сторонних библиотек, как конкурсный ответ  приниматься не будут.**

*UPDATE 24.02.2019 г.*

### Поздравляю победителя конкурса UModeL

Выполнены все непростые условия конкурса!
 Я уверен, что многие люди со временем будут возвращаться вновь и вновь в этот топик, чтобы использовать оригинальные решения автора ответа. Весь код очень подробно и доступно прокомментирован, что облегчает восприятие и освоение интересных комбинаций различных техник решения.

Comment: фрагментный шейдер, или канва?)

Comment: так то и то и другое js и такое же html5 api как dom и css =)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Только HTML и CSS. Border-color и rotate псевдоэлемента

*Сразу оговорюсь, что SVG предлагает намного большие возможности, по части форм и анимации (что видно из соседних ответов). Правда, есть пара минусов - это утяжеление кода разметки (при этом, стили и скрипты никто не отменял) и изучение SVG (хотя "порог входа" не высок, но с ходу понять не так просто).*

Для простых фигур, достаточно минимальной HTML-разметки, всё остальное же достигается с помощью CSS:

```css
.spin,
.spin:after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Толщина окружности */
  border: 3px solid grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: grey transparent grey transparent;
}
.spin {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 8px;
  /* Начальный угол */
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 1.5s ease;
}
.spin:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  /* Размер зазоров */
  transform: rotate(65deg);
}

#spin {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
}
#spin:hover+.spin {
  transform: rotate(720deg);
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font: 20px/40px "Times New Roman";
  text-align: center;
  transition: .3s ease;
  background: grey;
  color: white;
}
label:hover {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<input id="spin">
<div class="spin"></div><label for="spin">&nbsp;&nbsp;SPECIAL&nbsp;OPERATIONS&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
```

### Лоадер

Создание можно разделить на несколько этапов:

1. Создаём в HTML-разметке блок **`<div class="spin"></div>`**;
2. Создаём в CSS правило **`.spin, .spin:after {}`** и добавляем следующие свойства:

   - `width` и `height` - указываем одинаковые значения для ширины и высоты;
   - `box-sizing: border-box;` - чтобы толщина рамки не влияла на окружающие элементы;
   - `border: 3px solid grey;` - собственно, рамка с указанием толщины;
   - `border-radius: 50%;` - скругляем углы элемента, превращая т.о. в круг;
   - *(Внимание! Магия:)* Указываем разным сторонам рамки разный цвет. В данном случае, требуется задать, попарно для параллельных сторон, прозрачность и основной цвет - `border-color: grey transparent grey transparent;`.
3. Создаём правило **`.spin {}`** со свойствами:

   - `position: relative;` - для правильного позиционирования псевдоэлемента;
   - `transform: rotate(0deg);` - угол поворота в исходном положении блока;
   - `transition: 1.5s ease;` - задаём переход, чтобы происходила плавная анимация вращения, а не резкий скачок от начального положения к конечному
4. Создаём правило **`.spin:after {}`** и свойства:

   - `position: absolute; z-index: 1; top: -3px; left: -3px;` - размещаем и выравниваем псевдоэлемент относительно основного блока;
   - *(Внимание! Магия:)* С помощью `transform: rotate(65deg);` задаём угол поворота псевдоэлемента, тем самым меняя ширину зазоров.

***Принцип станет понятнее, если запустить пример ниже и подвигать ползунки:***

```js
var oControl=document.querySelector('.control'),oCode=document.querySelector('.code>pre');oControl.addEventListener('input',function(ev){document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--${ev.target.id}`,ev.target.value);if(ev.target.id=='spin_width'){oCode.innerText=oCode.innerText.replace(/border: \d+px/gi,`border: ${ev.target.value}px`)};if(ev.target.id=='spin_angle'){oCode.innerText=oCode.innerText.replace(/(угол[\s\S]+?rotate\()[-\d]+(deg\))/gi,`$1${ev.target.value}$2`)};if(ev.target.id=='spin-a_angle'){oCode.innerText=oCode.innerText.replace(/(зазоров[\s\S]+?rotate\()[-\d]+(deg\))/gi,`$1${ev.target.value}$2`)}});oControl.addEventListener('mouseover',function(ev){if(ev.target.id=='spin-a_angle'){document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--spin-a_color`,'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)')};if(ev.target.tagName=='INPUT'){oCode.className=ev.target.id}});oControl.addEventListener('mouseout',function(ev){if(ev.target.id=='spin-a_angle'){document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--spin-a_color`,'rgba(128, 128, 128, 1)')}})
```

```css
:root{--spin_color:rgba(128,128,128,1);--spin-a_color:rgba(128,128,128,1);--spin_width:3;--spin_angle:0;--spin-a_angle:65;--code-top:.2em}.wrapper_621x183{position:relative;display:block;width:621px;height:183px;min-width:621px;min-height:183px;max-width:621px;max-height:183px;margin:0 auto;border:0 dashed #ccc}.control{position:absolute;z-index:10;top:10px;right:10px;display:inline-flex;flex-flow:column nowrap;background:rgba(230,230,230,1);box-shadow:2px 10px 20px -7px rgba(0,0,0,.3);padding:5px;border-radius:5px;font:12px/20px 'Arial';text-align:center}.code{position:absolute;z-index:5;bottom:1px;left:10px;width:540px;height:98px;background:rgba(255,255,255,.9);box-shadow:inset 0 3px 23px -4px rgba(0,0,0,.3);padding:8px;border-radius:4px;overflow:hidden}.code>pre{position:absolute;top:var(--code-top);margin:0;font:13px 'Consolas','Courier New',monospace;transition:top 1.5s ease}.code>pre.spin_width{--code-top:.2em}.code>pre.spin_angle{--code-top:-8.5em}.code>pre.spin-a_angle{--code-top:-17.5em}.spin,.spin:after{display:inline-block;width:40px;height:40px;vertical-align:middle;box-sizing:border-box;border:calc(var(--spin_width) * 1px) solid var(--spin_color);border-radius:50%}.spin{position:relative;margin:10px 8px;border-color:var(--spin_color) transparent var(--spin_color) transparent;transform:rotate(calc(var(--spin_angle) * -1deg));transition:1.5s ease}.spin:after{content:'';position:absolute;z-index:1;top:calc(var(--spin_width) * -1px);left:calc(var(--spin_width) * -1px);border-color:var(--spin-a_color) transparent var(--spin-a_color) transparent;transform:rotate(calc(var(--spin-a_angle) * 1deg))}#spin{width:0;height:0;border:none;position:absolute}#spin:hover+.spin{transform:rotate(720deg)}label{display:inline-block;height:38px;vertical-align:middle;border-radius:10px;font:20px/40px 'Times New Roman';text-align:center;transition:.3s ease;background:grey;color:white}label:hover{background:black}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper_621x183"> <input id="spin"> <div class="spin"></div><label for="spin">&nbsp;&nbsp;SPECIAL&nbsp;OPERATIONS&nbsp;&nbsp;</label> <div class="control"> <div>Толщина окружности<br><input id="spin_width" min="1" max="20" value="3" type="range"></div><div>Начальный угол<br><input id="spin_angle" min="0" max="360" value="0" type="range"></div><div>Размер зазоров<br><input id="spin-a_angle" min="0" max="90" value="65" type="range"></div></div><div class="code"> <pre>.spin,<br>.spin:after {<br>  ···<br>  /* Толщина окружности */<br>  border: 3px solid grey;<br>  ···<br>}<br><br>.spin {<br>  ···<br>  /* Начальный угол */<br>  transform: rotate(-360deg);<br>  ···<br>}<br><br><br>.spin:after {<br>  ···<br>  /* Размер зазоров */<br>  transform: rotate(65deg);<br>  ···<br>}</pre> </div></div>
```

### Кнопка

Кнопка реализована через тег `<label>`, путём превращения его в блочный элемент с помощью свойства `display: block;` с дальнейшей стилизацией.

Использование `<label>` не случайно и вызвано желанием отказаться от скриптов в конкретном примере, при реализации столь простой задачи. А также, чтобы продемонстрировать один из способов применения данного тега.

Тег `<label>` (пер. *метка*), в данном примере, используется для "удалённого" управления состоянием элемента `<input>`. Т.е. сама *метка* может располагаться в любом месте страницы (при этом, совсем необязательно рядом с тегом `<input>` с которым она связана). Связь *метки* и `<input>` осуществляется с помощью атрибута **for**, в значении которого указывается **id** управляемого элемента:

```
<input id="spin"> <label for="spin">
```

Более того, *меток* указывающих на один и тот же элемент может быть несколько, размещаться они могут в произвольных местах документа и иметь разную стилизацию:

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 7px -3px black;
  transition: .3s ease;
}
label:hover { box-shadow: 0 2px 4px -2px black; }

.first {
  width: 130px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #f00;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.second {
  width: 130px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #0f0;
  border-radius: 0 8px 0 8px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, lime, gold, lime);
}

#spin {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
}
#spin:hover+.spin { transform: rotate(360deg); }

.spin,
.spin:after {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: grey transparent grey transparent;
}
.spin {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  transform: rotate(-360deg);
  transition: 1.5s ease;
}
.spin:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  transform: rotate(65deg);
}
```

```html
<label for="spin" class="first">Наведи на меня!</label>
<input id="spin"><div class="spin"></div>
<label for="spin" class="second">... Или на меня!</label>
```

**Важно!** Единственным условием для того, чтобы управляемый элемент своим состоянием мог воздействовать на соседний элемент, `<input>` должен располагаться в разметке непосредственно перед нужным элементом, а в CSS нужно использовать селектор выбора соседнего элемента - **`+`**:

```
input#spin:hover + div.spin { }
```

При этом сам `<input>` нужно скрыть, например, указав в стилях:

```
input#spin {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Почему не `display: none;`? Потому, что в некоторых браузерах перестают работать связи с метками с элементами скрытыми таким способом.

---

### Варианты

#### Один сегмент

Изменив всего один параметр - `border-color: grey grey grey transparent;`, можно получить вращение только одного зазора:

```css
.spin,
.spin:after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Толщина окружности */
  border: 3px solid grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: grey grey grey transparent;
}
.spin {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 8px;
  /* Начальный угол */
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 1.5s ease;
}
.spin:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  /* Размер зазоров */
  transform: rotate(65deg);
}

#spin {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
}
#spin:hover+.spin {
  transform: rotate(720deg);
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font: 20px/40px "Times New Roman";
  text-align: center;
  transition: .3s ease;
  background: grey;
  color: white;
}
label:hover {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<input id="spin">
<div class="spin"></div><label for="spin">&nbsp;&nbsp;SPECIAL&nbsp;OPERATIONS&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
```

#### Три сегмента

Чтобы получить три зазора, понадобится добавить ещё один псевдоэлемент **`.spin:before { }`**, продублировав для него свойства из **`.spin:after { }`**. Затем, у основного блока и псевдоэлементов задать свойство `transform: rotate( );` с разницей в *120deg*. Также, нужно применить нашу "магию" следующим образом - `border-color: grey transparent transparent transparent;`:

```css
.spin,
.spin:after,
.spin:before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Толщина окружности */
  border: 3px solid grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: grey transparent transparent transparent;
}
.spin {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 8px;
  /* Начальный угол */
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: 1.5s ease;
}
.spin:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  /* Размер зазоров */
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}
.spin:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  /* Размер зазоров */
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}

#spin {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
}
#spin:hover+.spin {
  transform: rotate(720deg);
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font: 20px/40px "Times New Roman";
  text-align: center;
  transition: .3s ease;
  background: grey;
  color: white;
}
label:hover {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<input id="spin">
<div class="spin"></div><label for="spin">&nbsp;&nbsp;SPECIAL&nbsp;OPERATIONS&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
```

*Варианты с другим количеством сегментов, резко увеличивают количество кода и усложняют разметку, поэтому реализация HTML+CSS будет нецелесообразной и лучше использовать другой способ.*

---

### Анимация появления рамки

Без сомнения, при творческом подходе, возможно создать почти любые эффекты, только средствами CSS. Но, нужно задуматься - "стоит ли овчинка выделки?" Возможно, реализация задумки, где с помощью другой технологии, можно обойтись парой-тройкой строк, не стоит "простыни" кода:

```css
.anistroke {
  position: relative;
  width: 140px;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  text-align: center;
  font: 18px/40px 'Arial';
  box-sizing: border-box;
  animation: aniblock 1.5s steps(1, end) forwards;
}

@keyframes aniblock {
  50%, 100% { border-bottom: 3px solid grey; }
}

.anistroke::after,
.anistroke::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -3px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-top: 0px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
}
.anistroke::after {
  left: 50%; border-left: 3px solid grey;
  animation: aniafter 1.5s linear forwards;
}
.anistroke::before {
  right: 50%; border-right: 3px solid grey;
  animation: anibefore 1.5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes aniafter {
  50% { left: 0%; height: 0px; width: 70px; }
  75% {
    height: 37px; width: 0px;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
  }
  75.01% { border-top: 3px solid grey; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; }
  100% {
    left: 0%; height: 37px; width: 30px;
    border-top: 3px solid grey;
    border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
  }
}

@keyframes anibefore {
  50% { right: 0%; height: 0px; width: 70px; }
  75% {
    height: 37px; width: 0px;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px solid grey;
  }
  75.01% { border-top: 3px solid grey; border-bottom: 0px solid transparent; }
  100% {
    right: 0%; height: 37px; width: 30px;
    border-top: 3px solid grey;
    border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="anistroke">anistroke</div>
```

Comment: Хороший ответ. Просьба хоть минимальные комментарии добавить. В частности как вырез достигается. И вторая просьба, второй вариант, если есть желание, сделать с одной кнопкой

Comment: ну наворотов добавь каких-нибудь. Мы же люди творческие, необязательно точь в точь, как в вопросе, я же вопрос выдумал, чтобы люди здесь проявили себя

Comment: просто шикарно и очень полезно для изучения. Люди не проходите мимо :) Изучайте и берите на вооружение!

Answer (score 17):

- Рассчитаем длину окружности при заданном радиусе `20px`

`C = 2 * 3.1415 * 20 = 125.66`

Длина половины окружности равна `62,83` Если взять длину, вырезаемого сегмента равным `10px` то формула stroke-dasharray будет такой: `stroke-dasharray="52.83 10"`

Первая цифра `52.83` в формуле, это длина черты, вторая `10` - пробел.

```css
.txt1  {fill:white; pointer-events:none;}
.rect {fill:gray;}
.txt1:hover {fill:white;}
.rect:hover {fill:black; transition:fill 0.5s all;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="320" height="60" viewBox="0 0 350 60" >   
   <g id="gr1" >
    
   <rect class="rect"  x="62" y="11" rx="10" width="250" height="40" />
       <text class="txt1" x="75" y="40" font-size="22" > SPECIAL OPERATIONS </text>
 <circle id="crc1" cx="30" cy="30" r="20"   stroke='grey' stroke-width="3" fill='transparent' 
        stroke-dasharray="52.83 10"  stroke-dashoffset="-35.41" >
       </circle>    
  </g>
</svg>
```

- Добавляем команду анимации вращения окружности.

На самом деле мы не вращаем окружность, а сдвигаем начало сегментов с помощью анимации `stroke-dashoffset`

При наведении курсора будет работать событие  `begin="gr1.mouseover"`  окружность будет вращаться в одну сторону.

При уходе курсора с надписи `begin="gr1.mouseout"` окружность будет вращаться в противоположную сторону.

**Анимация начинается при наведении курсора на надпись**

```css
.txt1  {fill:white; pointer-events:none;}
.rect {fill:gray;}
.txt1:hover {fill:white;}
.rect:hover {fill:black; transition:fill 0.5s all;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="320" height="60" viewBox="0 0 350 60" >   
   <g id="gr1" >
    
     <rect class="rect"  x="62" y="11" rx="10" width="250" height="40" />
      <text class="txt1" x="75" y="40" font-size="22" > SPECIAL OPERATIONS </text>
    </g>  
        <circle id="crc1" cx="30" cy="30" r="20"   stroke='grey' stroke-width="3" fill='transparent' 
           stroke-dasharray="52.83 10"  stroke-dashoffset="-4" >
          <animate
               attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
               values="-10;105.66;-10"
               dur="0.5s"
               begin="gr1.mouseover"
               repeatCount="1"
               restart="whenNotActive" /> 
        <animate
          attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
          values="105.66;0;105.66"
          dur="0.5s"
          begin="gr1.mouseout"
          repeatCount="1"
          restart="whenNotActive" /> 
       </circle>    
 
</svg>
```

### 2-ой вариант

Сегменты расположены вертикально

```css
.txt1  {fill:white; pointer-events:none;}
.rect {fill:gray;}
.txt1:hover {fill:white;}
.rect:hover {fill:black; transition:fill 0.5s all;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="320" height="60" viewBox="0 0 350 60" >   
   <g id="gr1" >
    
   <rect class="rect"  x="62" y="11" rx="10" width="250" height="40" />
       <text class="txt1" x="75" y="40" font-size="22" > SPECIAL OPERATIONS </text>
    </g>
 
 <circle id="crc1" cx="30" cy="30" r="20"   stroke='crimson' stroke-width="3" fill='transparent' 
        stroke-dasharray="52.83 10"  stroke-dashoffset="-35.41" >
       <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"  values="-10;105.66;-10"  dur="0.5s"   begin="gr1.mouseover" repeatCount="1" restart="whenNotActive" /> 
        <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"  values="105.66;0;105.66"    dur="0.5s"  begin="gr1.mouseout"   repeatCount="1" restart="whenNotActive" /> -->
  </circle>     
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробное пояснение как это делается!

Comment: Интересно уже глянуть :)))

Answer (score 8):

### Варианты анимаций

- Вращение одного сегмента
- Техника создания анимаций фигур с количеством сегментов больше двух
- Анимация симметричного заполнения фигур из одной точки

### Вращение одного сегмента

Также используем атрибут `stroke-dasharray` сначала для вырезания сегмента. При полной длине окружности равной `125,66` и размере вырезаемого сегмента `10px` получаем:

`stroke-dasharray="115.66 10"`

Анимация реализуется изменением `stroke-dashoffset` от максимума до минимума.

*Запуск анимации при наведении курсора*

```css
.txt1  {fill:white; transition: all  1s ease; pointer-events:none;}
.rect {fill:gray; transition: all  1s ease;}
.txt1:hover {fill:white; }
.rect:hover {fill:black; }
#crc1 
{
stroke:#d5d5d5;
stroke-width:3; 
fill:transparent;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="320" height="60" viewBox="0 0 350 60" >   
   <g id="gr1" >
    
   <rect class="rect"  x="62" y="11" rx="10" width="250" height="40" />
       <text class="txt1" x="75" y="40" font-size="22" > SPECIAL OPERATIONS </text>
    </g>

 <circle id="crc1" cx="30" cy="30" r="20"   
        stroke-dasharray="115.66 10"  stroke-dashoffset="-35.41" >
    <animate
      attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   values="105.66;-10"
   dur="0.35s"
   begin="gr1.mouseover"
   end="gr1.mouseout"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
   restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 
  </circle>  
  
</svg>
```

***Второй вариант***

Движение по видимой круговой траектории

К предыдущему коду добавляется вторая окружность, которая рисует траекторию движения сегмента.

```css
.txt1  {fill:white; pointer-events:none;}
.rect {fill:gray;}
.txt1:hover {fill:white;}
.rect:hover {fill:black; transition:fill 0.5s all;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="320" height="60" viewBox="0 0 350 60" >   
   <g id="gr1" >
    
   <rect class="rect"  x="62" y="11" rx="10" width="250" height="40" />
       <text class="txt1" x="75" y="40" font-size="22" > SPECIAL OPERATIONS </text>
    </g>
  <circle id="crc2" cx="30" cy="30" r="20"   stroke='black' stroke-width="3" fill='transparent'/> 
    <circle id="crc1" cx="30" cy="30" r="20"   stroke='#d5d5d5' stroke-width="3" fill='transparent' 
        stroke-dasharray="115.66 10"  stroke-dashoffset="-35.41" >
    <animate
      attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   values="105.66;-10"
   dur="0.35s"
   begin="gr1.mouseover"
   end="gr1.mouseout"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
   restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 
  </circle>  
  
</svg>
```

### Техника создания анимаций фигур с количеством сегментов больше двух

Для более углубленного изучения [есть топик на нашем сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/760290/28748), прочитав который, вы в совершенстве будете владеть данной техникой.

**Три сегмента**

Допустим нам необходимо создать три вращающихся сегмента.

делим полную длину окружности -  `125.66 / 3 = 41.88`

В одном сегменте `41,88px` должны уместится черта 33.88 + пробел `8px`

Итого получилось - `stroke-dasharray="33.88 8"`

```css
.txt1  {fill:white; pointer-events:none;}
.rect {fill:gray;}
.txt1:hover {fill:white;}
.rect:hover {fill:black; transition:fill 0.5s all;}
#crc1 {fill:transparent; stroke:#777777;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="320" height="60" viewBox="0 0 350 60" >   
   <g id="gr1" >
    
   <rect class="rect"  x="62" y="11" rx="10" width="250" height="40" />
       <text class="txt1" x="75" y="40" font-size="22" > SPECIAL OPERATIONS </text>
    </g>
 
 <circle id="crc1" cx="30" cy="30" r="20" stroke-width="3" 
        stroke-dasharray="33.88 8"  stroke-dashoffset="-4" >
    <animate
      attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   values="33.88;0"
   dur="0.2s"
   begin="gr1.mouseover"
   end="gr1.mouseout"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
   restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 
  </circle>  
  
</svg>
```

**Четыре сегмента**

`125,66 / 4 = 31,415`   `stroke-dasharray="23.415 8"`

```css
.txt1  {fill:white; pointer-events:none;}
.rect {fill:gray;}
.txt1:hover {fill:white;}
.rect:hover {fill:black; transition:fill 0.5s all;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="320" height="60" viewBox="0 0 350 60" >   
   <g id="gr1" >
    
   <rect class="rect"  x="62" y="11" rx="10" width="250" height="40" />
       <text class="txt1" x="75" y="40" font-size="22" > SPECIAL OPERATIONS </text>
    </g>
  
 <circle id="crc1" cx="30" cy="30" r="20"   stroke='#777777' stroke-width="3" fill='transparent' 
        stroke-dasharray="23.415 8"  stroke-dashoffset="-4" >
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"  values="54.83;0" dur="0.2s"   begin="gr1.mouseover"  end="gr1.mouseout" repeatCount="indefinite" restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 </circle>  
  
</svg>
```

**Пять сегментов**

`125,66 / 5 = 25.13`   `stroke-dasharray="15.13 10"`

```css
.txt1  {fill:white; pointer-events:none;}
.rect {fill:gray;}
.txt1:hover {fill:white;}
.rect:hover {fill:black; transition:fill 0.5s all;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="320" height="60" viewBox="0 0 350 60" >   
   <g id="gr1" >
    
   <rect class="rect"  x="62" y="11" rx="10" width="250" height="40" />
       <text class="txt1" x="75" y="40" font-size="22" > SPECIAL OPERATIONS </text>
    </g>
  
 <circle id="crc1" cx="30" cy="30" r="20"   stroke='#777777' stroke-width="3" fill='transparent' 
        stroke-dasharray="15.13 10"  stroke-dashoffset="-4" >
    <animate
      attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   values="54.83;0"
   dur="0.2s"
   begin="gr1.mouseover"
   end="gr1.mouseout"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
   restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 </circle>  
  
</svg>
```

### Анимация симметричного заполнения фигур из одной точки

В этой технике используется четыре параметра атрибута `stroke-dasharray`

Проще понять на отрезке прямой, у которой в отличии от окружности не смыкаются конечные точки.

Допустим имеем такую запись `stroke-dasharray="10 20"`
 Она означает, что чередуются на всей длине линии черта `10px`  и пробел `20px`

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="320" height="60" viewBox="0 0 350 60" >   
    
 <polyline points="0,30 350,30" stroke-dasharray="10 20"   stroke='#777777' stroke-width="3" fill='transparent' 
          stroke-dashoffset="0" />
</svg>
```

Теперь добавляем ещё два параметра

`stroke-dasharray="10 20 40 40"`

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="320" height="60" viewBox="0 0 340 60" >   
    
 <polyline points="0,30 350,30" stroke-dasharray="10 20 40 40"   stroke='#777777' stroke-width="3" fill='transparent' 
          stroke-dashoffset="0" />
</svg>
```

В этом варианте 10 - черта, 20 - пробел, 40 черта, 40 пробел и снова 10 - черта 20 - пробел и так до конца линии.

**Анимация линии из средней точки**

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="320" height="60" viewBox="0 0 350 60" >   
    
 <path id="path" d="M 0 30 L 340 30"    stroke='#777777' stroke-width="3" fill='transparent' 
          stroke-dashoffset="0" >
     <animate
    attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
    from="0 170 0 170"
    to="0 0 340 0"
    dur="4s"
    begin="0s"
    repeatCount="1"
    restart="whenNotActive"
    fill="freeze"  />  
   </path>
</svg>
```

Линия длиной `340px`, половина линии, средняя точка `170px`

`from="0 170 0 170"` начало анимации - черта - 0, пробел длиною 170 px, черта - 0, пробел длиною 170 px то есть вся линия спрятана.

`to="0 0 340 0"` - черта длиною `0` пробел длиною `0`, черта 340px, пробел - ноль. 
Так как на трех позициях нули, а одна черта имеет максимальную длину равную полной длине линии, то линия будет показана полностью.

*На этом принципе действуют остальные примеры рисования из средней точки*

**Анимация рисования бордюра из средней точки**

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
   width="320" height="60" viewBox="0 0 350 60">
         <path id="shape" fill="none" stroke-width="3" stroke="#656E76"
              d="M 38.8 3.35 H 3.15 V 43.65 H 155.75 V 3.35 H 120.2" />
 <animate xlink:href="#shape" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" from="0 152.2 0 152.2" to="0 0 304.4 0" begin="0s" dur="1.4s" />
 </g>
</svg>
```

**Анимация вертикального эллипса**

```css
.txt1  {fill:white; pointer-events:none;}
.rect {fill:gray; transition: 0.8s  all;}
.txt1:hover {fill:white;}
.rect:hover {fill:crimson; transition: 0.8s all;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="320" height="60" viewBox="0 0 350 60" >   
   <g id="gr1" >
     <rect class="rect"  x="62" y="11" rx="10" width="250" height="40" />
       <text class="txt1" x="75" y="40" font-size="22" > SPECIAL OPERATIONS </text>
   </g>
     <g transform="translate(20 9)">
  <path d="m31 22a9 17 0 0 1-9 17 9 17 0 0 1-9-17 9 17 0 0 1 9-17 9 17 0 0 1 9 17z" 
    stroke='#d0d0d0' stroke-width="3" fill='transparent' />  
  
  <path d="m31 22a9 17 0 0 1-9 17 9 17 0 0 1-9-17 9 17 0 0 1 9-17 9 17 0 0 1 9 17z" 
    stroke="crimson" stroke-width="3" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="0 42  0 42" stroke-dashoffset="-21" >
  <animate
    attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
    from="0 42 0  42"
    to="0 0 84 0"
    dur="0.4s"
    begin="gr1.mouseover"
    repeatCount="1"
    restart="whenNotActive"
    fill="freeze"  /> 
   <animate
     attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
     from="0 0 84 0"
     to="0 42 0 42"
     dur="0.4s"
     begin="gr1.mouseout"
     repeatCount="1"
     restart="whenNotActive"
     fill="freeze"  />
  </path>
     </g>  
</svg>
```

**Горизонтальный эллипс**

```css
.txt1  {fill:white; pointer-events:none;}
.rect {fill:gray;}
.txt1:hover {fill:white;}
.rect:hover {fill:crimson; transition: 0.5s all;}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="320" height="60" viewBox="0 0 350 60" >   
   <g id="gr1" >
     <rect class="rect"  x="62" y="11" rx="10" width="250" height="40" />
       <text class="txt1" x="75" y="40" font-size="22" > SPECIAL OPERATIONS </text>
   </g>
     <g transform="translate(10 9)">
  <path d="m41 22a19 13 0 0 1-19 13 19 13 0 0 1-19-13 19 13 0 0 1 19-13 19 13 0 0 1 19 13z" 
    stroke='#d0d0d0' stroke-width="3" fill='transparent' />  
  
  <path d="m41 22a19 13 0 0 1-19 13 19 13 0 0 1-19-13 19 13 0 0 1 19-13 19 13 0 0 1 19 13z" 
    stroke="crimson" stroke-width="3" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="0 50.5  0 50.5" stroke-dashoffset="-25" >
  <animate
   attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   from="0 50.5 0 50.5"
   to="0 0 101 0"
   stroke-dashoffset="25"
   dur="0.8s"
   begin="gr1.mouseover"
   repeatCount="1"
   restart="whenNotActive"
   fill="freeze"  /> 
   
    <animate
   attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   from="0 0 101 0"
   to="0 50.5 0 50.5"
   stroke-dashoffset="25"
   dur="0.8s"
   begin="gr1.mouseout"
   repeatCount="1"
   restart="whenNotActive"
   fill="freeze"  /> 
  </path>
     </g>  
</svg>
```

Comment: Как всегда на высоте! Беру на вооружение!

Comment: @leonid Наткнулся на топик с детальной разборкой stroke-dasharray. Вспомнил, что ты, как-то хотел поразбираться с ней

Answer (score 7):

От меня, как и в [прошлый раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/924210/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8/927012#927012) WebGL изврат в 100 строчек кода вместе с разметкой и с небольшим бонусом в виде displacement'a

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все это математика во фрагментном шейдере и те же самые signed distance fields, о которых я уже писал в посте по ссылке в начале

Если коротко то вся соль, вот тут:

```
vec3 paintCircle (vec2 uv, vec2 center, float rad, float width) {

    // координаты пикселя относительно центра "круга"
    vec2 diff = center - uv;

    // расстояние до этой точки
    float len = length(diff);

    // расстояние до "круга"
    float circle = smoothstep(rad - width, rad, len) - 
                   smoothstep(rad, rad + width, len);

    // поворот текстурных координат относительно центра "круга"
    vec2 at = (uv-center) * rotate2d(rotation);

    // вырезание 2 частей окружности
    if (at.x - 0.05 < 0. && at.x + 0.05 > 0.)
        circle -= 1.0; 

    return vec3(circle);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <script>
        let started = new Date().getTime();
        let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        document.body.append(canvas);
        let size = canvas.width = canvas.height = 150;
        let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');

        let pid = gl.createProgram();

        shader(`
            attribute vec2 coords;
            void main(void) {
                gl_Position = vec4(coords.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
            }
        `, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);

        shader(`
            precision highp float;

            uniform float time;
            uniform float rotation;
            uniform float displace;

            mat2 rotate2d(float angle) {
                return mat2(cos(angle),-sin(angle),
                            sin(angle), cos(angle));
            }

            float displacement(vec2 v1, vec2 v2, float strength, float speed) {
                return sin(
                    dot(normalize(v1), normalize(v2)) * strength + time * speed
                ) / displace;
            }

            vec3 paintCircle (vec2 uv, vec2 center, float rad, float width) {
                vec2 diff = center-uv;
                float len = length(diff);
                len += displacement(diff, vec2(0.0, 1.0), 5.0, 2.0);
                len -= displacement(diff, vec2(1.0, 0.0), 5.0, 2.0);
                float circle = smoothstep(rad-width, rad, len) - smoothstep(rad, rad+width, len);
                vec2 at = (uv-center) * rotate2d(rotation);
                if (at.x - 0.05 < 0. && at.x + 0.05 > 0.)
                    circle -= 1.0;
                return vec3(circle);
            }

            void main(void) {
                vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / ${size}.;
                vec3 color = paintCircle(uv, vec2(0.5), 0.3, 0.1);
                color *= vec3(uv.x, uv.y, 0.7-uv.y*uv.x);
                color += paintCircle(uv, vec2(0.5), 0.3, 0.03);
                gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0-color, color.r+color.g+color.b);
            }
        `, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        gl.linkProgram(pid);
        gl.useProgram(pid);

        let array = new Float32Array([-1,  3, -1, -1, 3, -1]);
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, array, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        let al = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "coords");
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(al, 2 /*components per vertex */, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(al);

        let time = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');
        let rot = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'rotation');
        let displacement = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'displace');
        gl.uniform1f(displacement, 500);

        draw();
        var rotate = 0;

        function draw() {
            requestAnimationFrame(draw);
            let dt = new Date().getTime() - started;
            gl.uniform1f(rot, rotate * dt / 300);
            gl.uniform1f(time, dt / 1000);
            gl.viewport(0, 0, size, size);
            gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        }

        function shader(src, type) {
            let sid = gl.createShader(type);
            gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
            gl.compileShader(sid);
            gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
        }

        canvas.onmouseenter = function () {rotate = 1;};
        canvas.onmouseleave = function () {rotate = 0;};
    </script>
    <input type="range" min="10" max="1000" value="500" onchange="gl.uniform1f(displacement, this.value)">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT все возможно, однако нужно ли, пост все равно не участвует в конкурсе, это я так решил развлечь себя, в перерыве от работы.

Comment: странное ощущение, что крутится белая полоска над цельным кругом, а не две раздельные половинки

Comment: @Grundy видимо так оно и устроено)