# Как сделать разовую анимацию символа бесконечность?

Tags: css, css3, svg, анимация, css-animation

У меня есть знак бесконечности в `svg`, у которого имеется анимация заполнения своего контура.

```css
.black {
  stroke: black;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 20;
  stroke-dasharray: 923.0598754882812;
  animation: dash 5s ease 1;
}

.rainbow1 {
  stroke: url(#linear);
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 20;
  stroke-dasharray: 923.0598754882812;
  animation: dash 5s ease 1;
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 923.0598754882812;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -923.0598754882812;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -1846.119750976562;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="625" height="600">
  <path class="black" d="M200 200
           Q250 100 400 200
           T600 200
           Q500 100 400 200
           T200 200"
    /> 
</svg>

<svg width="625" height="600">
  <defs>
   <linearGradient id="linear" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
     <stop offset="0%"   stop-color="#05a"/>
     <stop offset="50%"  stop-color="#a55"/>
     <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#0a5"/>
   </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 
  <path class="rainbow1" d="M200,210 
           Q275 100 400 200
           T600 200
           Q510 100 400 200
           T200 200"
        />
</svg>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы контур проходил только один (а не двойной) цикл и был с и имел более плавную и четкую форму без обрубка-стыка на конце. Вот такую:

```css
    #infinity {
      position: relative;
      width: 212px;
      height: 100px;
      box-sizing: content-box;
    }
    #infinity:before,
    #infinity:after {
      content: "";
      box-sizing: content-box;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      border: 20px solid black;
      border-radius: 50px 50px 0 50px;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
    #infinity:after {
      left: auto;
      right: 0;
      border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 0;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
```

```html
<div id="infinity"></div>
```

Comment: Добавлен ответ [Анимация симметричного заполнения фигур из одной точки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/944893/28748)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Так?

```html
<svg width="200px" height="200px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path fill="none" d="M24.3,30C11.4,30,5,43.3,5,50s6.4,20,19.3,20c19.3,0,32.1-40,51.4-40 C88.6,30,95,43.3,95,50s-6.4,20-19.3,20C56.4,70,43.6,30,24.3,30z" stroke="#000" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="0 256.588928222656257 0">
      <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="0;256.58892822265625" dur="1" fill="freeze"></animate>
    </path>
  </svg>
```

Comment: поставил плюсик.Также хочу спросить  можно объяснения к коду?

Comment: Что именно не понятно?

Comment: да собственно говоря ничего.

Comment: @Kvilios спасибо! А можно делать задержку анимации, к примеру если не доскролил страницу, то она еще не отрабатывает? Или здесь уже без `js` никак?

Comment: @Вася добавьте к тегу animate begin="3s" и анимация начнется через 3 секунды. Через JS также можете вызвать beginElement у элемента из DOM по своему событию (будь то скролл или клик).

Comment: @Избытоксусликов в данном примере используется svg у которого прописан векторный путь (собственно это и есть сама иконка бесконечности). Также для анимации используется тег animate, у которого задан сам объект (обводка), значение откуда и до куда анимировать (начальная и конечная точки), длительность анимации и стоп анимации на последнем "кадре"

Comment: @Kvilios спасибо

Comment: @Kvilios покажу на примере https://jsfiddle.net/p2wa69qn/
При пролистывании хочу, чтобы на `waypoint` начала срабатывать анимация, но в моем случае это не происходит, объект появляется сразу без анимации

Comment: @Вася Оберните svg в объект, а затем можно использовать ф-ии $("#infinity-counter").show().beginElement();. Вот пример: https://jsfiddle.net/8jyx7w1u/ Из-за того, что браузер кэширует svg - анимация повторно не проигрывается. Такая обёртка помогает избежать этой проблемы.

Comment: @Kvilios понял, спасибо большое за помощь и объяснения! К слову, у меня даже работает без `beginElement()`, а на него в консоли ругается

Comment: @Вася, да, я тупанул, его надо без обёртки jQuery вызывать, можно через getElementById("infinity-counter")[0].beginElement(); И желательно убрать id из самой svg

Answer (score 7):

### Анимация симметричного заполнения фигур из одной точки

Подробно рассказано об этой оригинальной технике [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/944006/28748). Смотрите вторую половину ответа.

Патч взял из ответа @Kvilios
 Максимальная длина его - `257px`. Половина - `128.5px` Четверть пути - `64.2px`.   Эти цифры понадобятся для сдвига начала `path` командой `stroke-dashoffset="128.5"`

**Пример заполнения фигуры из середины `path`**

Обратите внимание, что фигура одновременно, симметрично заполняется из центра, пока края не сомкнутся.

```css
body {background:#2F2F2F;}
.container 
{
 width:50%;
 height:50%;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 20 100 100">
  
  <path fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="10"  />  

 <path id="path1" fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke="greenyellow" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="31.1" stroke-dasharray="0 128.5" >  
      <animate
     xlink:href="#path1"
  attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
  values="0 128.5 0 128.5;0 0 257 0"
  begin="btn.click"
  dur="4s"
  fill="freeze"/> 
 </path> 
 
 <g id="btn" transform="translate(12 0)">
      <rect x="20" y="84" width="35" height="15" rx="5" fill="none" stroke="dodgerblue"/>
      <text x="24" y="94" font-size="10" fill="crimson" >Центр</text>
    </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

### Комплексный пример заполнения

Начать заполнение можно из любой точки фигуры, для этого надо сдвинуть начало рисования линии от начала с помощью изменения числового значения атрибута `stroke-dashoffset`

В приложении кнопка **L**, - запускает рисование с левого края

**R** - справа  (right)

**T** - сверху (top)

**C** - центр (center)

**B** - снизу (bottom)

На эти обозначения ориентируйтесь при разборе кода `id="btn_c"`, `<path id="center"`

```css
.container
{
width:40%;
height:40%;  
 background:black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 25 100 100">
  
  <path fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke="#d3d3d3" stroke-width="10"  />  
       <!-- Средняя точка начала анимации в центре слева stroke-dashoffset="31.1" -->
 <path id="center" fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke="crimson" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="31.1" stroke-dasharray="0 128.5" >  
      <animate
        attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
        values="0 128.5 0 128.5;0 0 257 0"
        begin="btn_C.click"
        dur="4s"
        restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 </path> 
   <!-- Средняя точка слева stroke-dashoffset="-159.5" -->
     <path id="Left" fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke="yellowgreen" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="-159.5" stroke-dasharray="0 128.5" >  
      <animate
        attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
        values="0 128.5 0 128.5;0 0 257 0"
        begin="btn_L.click"
        dur="4s"
        restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 </path>  
 
    <!-- Средняя точка слева сверху stroke-dashoffset="128.5" -->
     <path id="Top" fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke="gold" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="128.5" stroke-dasharray="0 128.5" >  
      <animate
        attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
        values="0 128.5 0 128.5;0 0 257 0"
        begin="btn_T.click"
        dur="4s"
        restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 </path> 
     <!-- Средняя точка справа внизу  stroke-dashoffset="192.7" -->
  <path id="Bottom" fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="192.7" stroke-dasharray="0 128.5" >  
      <animate
        attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
        values="0 128.5 0 128.5;0 0 257 0"
        begin="btn_B.click"
        dur="4s"
        restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 </path>   
 
        <!-- Средняя точка справа   stroke-dashoffset="223.9" -->
  <path id="Bottom" fill="none" d="M24.3 30C11.4 30 5 43.3 5 50s6.4 20 19.3 20c19.3 0 32.1-40 51.4-40C88.6 30 95 43.3 95 50s-6.4 20-19.3 20C56.4 70 43.6 30 24.3 30z" stroke="purple" stroke-width="10" stroke-dashoffset="223.9" stroke-dasharray="0 128.5" >  
      <animate
        attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
        values="0 128.5 0 128.5;0 0 257 0"
        begin="btn_R.click"
        dur="4s"
        restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 </path> 
 
 
 
 <g id="btn_L" transform="translate(-17 0)" >
      <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="#B2B2B2"/>
      <text x="25" y="95" font-size="10" fill="green" >L</text>
    </g>  
 <g id="btn_C" transform="translate(3 0)">
      <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="#B2B2B2"/>
      <text x="24" y="95" font-size="10" fill="crimson" >C</text>
    </g> 
    
     <g id="btn_T" transform="translate(23 0)" >
      <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="dodgerblue"/>
      <text x="24" y="95" font-size="10" fill="orange" >T</text>
        </g>  
  <g id="btn_B" transform="translate(43 0)">
 <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="#B2B2B2"/>
  <text x="25" y="95" font-size="10" fill="dodgerblue" >B</text>
  </g>   
      <g id="btn_R" transform="translate(63 0)">
     <rect x="20" y="84" width="15" height="15" rx="7.5" fill="none" stroke="#B2B2B2"/>
       <text x="25" y="95" font-size="10" fill="purple" >R</text>
    </g> 
</svg>
</div>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://codepen.io/Alexandr_T/pen/GzXLXz)**

Comment: супер! Крутое объяснение! Поставил бы вам много плюсов или дополнительно к ответу выше засчитал, как еще один правильный ответ, но так уже нельзя.. Значит 100 плюсов вам в карму, всех благ!

Comment: по ссылке перешел и так и сделал! Буду внимательно читать как все это правильно делается. Если встречу еще ваши хорошие ответы, то и там непременно сделаю тоже самое)

Comment: @Вася Радуйся, если получил ответ Александра, ибо тебе никогда не придется задавать вопросы по этой теме :)

Answer (score 4):

Почти не менял оригинальный код...

```css
#infinity {
  position: relative;
  width: 212px;
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  animation: clip-grow 4s;
}
#infinity:before,
#infinity:after {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 20px solid black;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 0 50px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#infinity:after {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

@keyframes clip-grow {
 from{clip-path: circle(0px at 106px 50px);}
 to  {clip-path: circle(200px at 106px 50px);}
}
```

```html
<div id="infinity"></div>
```