# Нестандартная анимация обводки фигур SVG

Tags: javascript, css, html5, svg, css-animation

Необходимо реализовать анимацию обводки контуров кнопки.
Анимационные линии должны идти из одной точки в разных  направлениях и встречаться одновременно друг с другом в другой точке.

1. Анимация начинается из средней точки нижнего бордюра кнопки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Промежуточный этап

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Промежуточный этап

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Финальное положение - линии смыкаются в одной точке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал использовать технику рисования линий с помощью изменения атрибутов `stroke-dasharray` и `stroke-dashoffset`

*Анимация начинается после наведения курсора*

```css
body {
  max-width: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #3A92CE;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active, a:visited {
  color: gold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
 
}

.svg-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 320px;
  max-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  
}

.rect-shape {
  stroke:#E4E4E4;
  stroke-width:2;
  fill:transparent;
 }

.text {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #E4E4E4;
  top: -48px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="svg-container">
     <a class="magic-link" href="#">
        <svg class="gradient" id="svg1" height="60" width="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
              <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <rect class="rect-shape" id="rect1" height="60" width="320"   stroke-width="2"  />
    <polyline id="p1" points="0 0, 320 0, 320 60, 0 60, 0 0"  fill="transparent" stroke="#E4E4E4"
           stroke-width="8"   stroke-dashoffset="760" stroke-dasharray="760 760" >
     <animate id="an1"
      attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   values="760;0"
   dur="4s"
   begin="p1.mouseover"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" /> 
     
   </polyline>  
  
          <div class="text">Bottom middle</div>
        </svg>
     </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Анимация рисования бордюра получилась  из одной точки, но только одной линией

Как сделать анимацию с помощью двух линий, как показано на картинках выше.

Comment: [Во втором ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1022131/28748) добавлен пример анимации лого Гитхаба. На мой взгляд прикольно получилось.

Comment: Да,  здорово получилось. Возьму на заметку.

Answer (score 5):

Для реализации идеи одновременной анимации рисования с помощью двух линий, можно использовать атрибут `stroke-dasharray`. 
У атрибута `stroke-dasharray` имеется несколько пар параметров:

`stroke-dasharray = "черта пробел черта пробел"`

**Остается вычислить необходимые значения этих параметров:**

Длина периметра кнопки: `320 + 60 + 320 + 60 = 760`

Половина длины периметра, - это будет длина одной линии - `380px`

Чтобы скрыть линии на начальном этапе рисования записываем `stroke-dasharray ="0 380 0 380"`

Другими словами - черта - `0`, пробел - `380`, черта - `0`, пробел - `380`

**Итого:**  длина черты - `0`, длина пробела - `760` то есть линия будет полностью скрыта

Чтобы полностью показать обе сомкнутые линии: `stroke-dasharray ="0 0 760 0"`

Записываем формулу анимации: `values="0 380 0 380; 0 0 760 0"`

```css
body {
  max-width: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #3A92CE;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active, a:visited {
  color: gold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
 
}

.svg-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 320px;
  max-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  
}

.rect-shape {
  stroke:#E4E4E4;
  stroke-width:2;
  fill:transparent;
 }

.text {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #E4E4E4;
  top: -48px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="svg-container">
     <a class="magic-link" href="#">
        <svg class="gradient" id="svg1" height="60" width="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
              <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <rect class="rect-shape" id="rect1" height="60" width="320"   stroke-width="2"  />
    <polyline id="p1" points="0 0, 320 0, 320 60, 0 60, 0 0"  fill="transparent" stroke="#E4E4E4"
           stroke-width="8"   stroke-dashoffset="600" stroke-dasharray="0 380" >
     <animate id="an1"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 380 0 380;0 0 760 0"
   dur="1s"
   begin="p1.mouseover"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" /> 
  <animate id="an2"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 0 760 0;0 380 0 380"
   dur="0.5s"
   begin="an1.end"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" />  
   
   </polyline>  
   
    
          <div class="text">Bottom middle</div>
        </svg>
     </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Чтобы начать анимацию из другой точки, например из середины верхней линии кнопки, нужно сдвинуть начальную точку анимации с помощью команды `stroke-dashoffset="220"`

**Top-middle**

```css
body {
  max-width: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #4A4A4A;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active, a:visited {
  color: gold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
 
}

.svg-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 320px;
  max-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  
}

.rect-shape {
  stroke:#E4E4E4;
  stroke-width:2;
  fill:transparent;
 }

.text {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #E4E4E4;
  top: -48px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}






          <div class="text">Top middle</div>
        </svg>
     </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="svg-container">
     <a class="magic-link" href="#">
        <svg class="gradient" id="svg1" height="60" width="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
              <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <rect class="rect-shape" id="rect1" height="60" width="320"   stroke-width="2"  />
    <polyline id="p1" points="0 0, 320 0, 320 60, 0 60, 0 0"  fill="transparent" stroke="#E4E4E4"
           stroke-width="8"   stroke-dashoffset="220" stroke-dasharray="0 380" >
     <animate id="an1"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 380 0 380;0 0 760 0"
   dur="1s"
   begin="p1.mouseover"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" /> 
  <animate id="an2"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 0 760 0;0 380 0 380"
   dur="0.5s"
   begin="an1.end"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" />  
   
   </polyline>  
      
          <div class="text">Top middle</div>
        </svg>
     </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Top-left**

```css
body {
  max-width: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #4A4A4A;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active, a:visited {
  color: gold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
 
}

.svg-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 320px;
  max-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  
}

.rect-shape {
  stroke:#E4E4E4;
  stroke-width:2;
  fill:transparent;
 }

.text {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #E4E4E4;
  top: -48px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="svg-container">
     <a class="magic-link" href="#">
        <svg class="gradient" id="svg1" height="60" width="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
              <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <rect class="rect-shape" id="rect1" height="60" width="320"   stroke-width="2"  />
    <polyline id="p1" points="0 0, 320 0, 320 60, 0 60, 0 0"  fill="transparent" stroke="#E4E4E4"
           stroke-width="8"   stroke-dashoffset="380" stroke-dasharray="0 380" >
     <animate id="an1"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 380 0 380;0 0 760 0"
   dur="1s"
   begin="p1.mouseover"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" /> 
  <animate id="an2"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 0 760 0;0 380 0 380"
   dur="0.5s"
   begin="an1.end"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" />  
   
   </polyline>  
   
    
          <div class="text">Top left</div>
        </svg>
     </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Top-right**

```css
body {
  max-width: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #3A92CE;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active, a:visited {
  color: gold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
 
}

.svg-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 320px;
  max-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  
}

.rect-shape {
  stroke:#E4E4E4;
  stroke-width:2;
  fill:transparent;
 }

.text {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #E4E4E4;
  top: -48px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="svg-container">
     <a class="magic-link" href="#">
        <svg class="gradient" id="svg1" height="60" width="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
              <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <rect class="rect-shape" id="rect1" height="60" width="320"   stroke-width="2"  />
    <polyline id="p1" points="0 0, 320 0, 320 60, 0 60, 0 0"  fill="transparent" stroke="#E4E4E4"
           stroke-width="8"   stroke-dashoffset="60" stroke-dasharray="0 380" >
     <animate id="an1"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 380 0 380;0 0 760 0"
   dur="1s"
   begin="p1.mouseover"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" /> 
  <animate id="an2"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 0 760 0;0 380 0 380"
   dur="0.5s"
   begin="an1.end"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" />  
   
   </polyline>  
   
    
          <div class="text">Top right</div>
        </svg>
     </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Bottom-left**

```css
body {
  max-width: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: purple;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active, a:visited {
  color: gold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
 
}

.svg-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 320px;
  max-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  
}

.rect-shape {
  stroke:#E4E4E4;
  stroke-width:2;
  fill:transparent;
 }

.text {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #E4E4E4;
  top: -48px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="svg-container">
     <a class="magic-link" href="#">
        <svg class="gradient" id="svg1" height="60" width="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
              <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <rect class="rect-shape" id="rect1" height="60" width="320"   stroke-width="2"  />
    <polyline id="p1" points="0 0, 320 0, 320 60, 0 60, 0 0"  fill="transparent" stroke="#E4E4E4"
           stroke-width="8"   stroke-dashoffset="440" stroke-dasharray="0 380" >
     <animate id="an1"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 380 0 380;0 0 760 0"
   dur="1s"
   begin="p1.mouseover"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" /> 
  <animate id="an2"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 0 760 0;0 380 0 380"
   dur="0.5s"
   begin="an1.end"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" />  
   
   </polyline>  
   
    
          <div class="text">Bottom left</div>
        </svg>
     </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Bottom-right**

```css
body {
  max-width: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: purple;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus, a:active, a:visited {
  color: gold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
 
}

.svg-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 320px;
  max-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  
}

.rect-shape {
  stroke:#E4E4E4;
  stroke-width:2;
  fill:transparent;
 }

.text {
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight:bold;
  line-height: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #E4E4E4;
  top: -48px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}






  </div>
</section>
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="svg-container">
     <a class="magic-link" href="#">
        <svg class="gradient" id="svg1" height="60" width="320" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient">
              <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
              <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#EB3349" />
            </linearGradient>
          </defs>
          <rect class="rect-shape" id="rect1" height="60" width="320"   stroke-width="2"  />
    <polyline id="p1" points="0 0, 320 0, 320 60, 0 60, 0 0"  fill="transparent" stroke="#E4E4E4"
           stroke-width="8"   stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="0 380" >
     <animate id="an1"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 380 0 380;0 0 760 0"
   dur="1s"
   begin="p1.mouseover"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" /> 
  <animate id="an2"
      attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   values="0 0 760 0;0 380 0 380"
   dur="0.5s"
   begin="an1.end"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive" />  
   
   </polyline>  
   
    
          <div class="text">Bottom right</div>
        </svg>
     </a>
```

Связанный вопрос: [Как сделать разовую анимацию символа бесконечность?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/944893/28748)

Answer (score 2):

Используя технику анимации рисования из одной точки, можно дополнительно оживить любой загрузчик.

В качестве примера создадим загрузчик похожий на лоадер сайта `learn.javascript.ru`

**Данные для расчета:**

длина контура загрузчика - `379px`

Половина длины контура загрузчика будет равна длине одной анимационной линии - `169,5px`

Изменение параметров для stroke-dasharray - `values="0 169.6 0 169.6; 0 0 339 0"`

**Сценарий анимации:**

1. Рисуется контур двумя линиями из одной точки
2. Появляется вращающийся двух сегментный круг
3. Вращение круга

```css
path {
fill:none;
stroke:#C0C0C0;
stroke-width:10;
}
circle {
fill:none;
stroke:silver;
stroke-width:10; 
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1" width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 250 250" style="border:1px solid grey">

   <path d="m125 75c30 0 50 22 50 50 0 28-20 50-50 51C100 176 87 175 75 175c0 0 0-15 0-25 0-10 0-17 0-25C75 95 90 75 125 75Z"  stroke-dasharray="0 169.6 0 169.6"  stroke-dashoffset="132.5" >
    <animate id="an_body"
   attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   begin="svg1.click"
   dur="1s"
   values="0 169.6 0 169.6; 0 0 339 0"
   fill="freeze" />
  </path>
 
 <circle id="crc1" cx="125" cy="125" r="25"  opacity="0" stroke-dasharray="50 28.5" />

   <animate id="an_crc"
     attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
  begin="an_opacity.end"
  dur="0.30s"
  values="78.5;0"
  repeatCount="indefinite" />  
  </circle>
   <animate id="an_opacity"
     xlink:href="#crc1"
  attributeName="opacity"
  begin="an_body.end"
  dur="1s"
  values="0;1"
  fill="freeze"  />
   <text x="100" y="220" font-size="32px"> Click me </text>
  
</svg>
```

**Анимация четырёх углов квадрата**

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="background:black">

<rect id="rect1" x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" fill="black" stroke="cyan" stroke-width="6" stroke-dasharray="0 100 0 100 0 100 0 100" stroke-dashoffset="25" >
  <animate id="an_body"
   attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   begin="0s;an_angle.end+1s"
   dur="2s"
   values="0 100, 0 100, 0 100, 0 100 ;50 50, 50 50, 50 50, 50 50"
   fill="freeze" /> 
  <animate id="an_angle"
   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   begin="an_body.end+2s"
   dur="2s"
   values="25; -375"
   fill="freeze" />   
  </rect>
 
</svg>
```

**Анимация эмблемы Adobe**

```html
<svg height="50%" width="50%" viewBox='0 0 105 93' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
<path d='M66,0h39v93zM38,0h-38v93zM52,35l25,58h-16l-8-18h-18z' stroke-dasharray="0 312.5, 0 312.5" stroke-dashoffset="0" fill='none' stroke="red">
   <animate id="an_adobe"
   attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   begin="-1s"
   dur="6s"
   values="0 312.5, 0 312.5;0 0, 312.5 0"
   fill="freeze" />
 <animate id="an_fill"
   attributeName="fill"
   begin="an_adobe.end"
   dur="2s"
   values="white;red"
   fill="freeze" />  
</path>
</svg>
```

### Анимация лого Гитхаба

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="300" viewBox="-20 -50 300 300"  >
 <g  style="opacity:0;">
      <path fill="#9EDCF2" opacity="1" d="M200.9 199.8c0 13.9-32.2 25.1-71.9 25.1 -39.7 0-71.9-11.3-71.9-25.1 0-13.9 32.2-25.1 71.9-25.1C168.7 174.7 200.9 185.9 200.9 199.8L200.9 199.8zM200.9 199.8">
      
      </path>
      <defs>
        
     <path id="shade_of_paws" d="M98.1 244.8c1.6 7.5 5.5 11.9 9.4 14.5l41.1 0c5-3.4 10.1-9.8 10.1-21.8v-31c0 0 0.6-7.7 7.7-10.2 0 0 4.1-2.9-0.3-4.5 0 0-19.5-1.6-19.5 14.4v23.6c0 0 0.8 8.7-3.8 12.3v-29.2c0 0 0.3-9.3 5.1-12.8 0 0 3.2-5.7-3.8-4.2 0 0-13.4 1.9-14 17.6l-0.3 30h-3.2l-0.3-30c-0.6-15.6-14-17.6-14-17.6 -7-1.6-3.8 4.2-3.8 4.2 4.8 3.5 5.1 12.8 5.1 12.8v29.5c-4.6-3.3-3.8-12.6-3.8-12.6v-23.6c0-16-19.5-14.4-19.5-14.4 -4.5 1.6-0.3 4.5-0.3 4.5 7 2.6 7.7 10.2 7.7 10.2v21.7L98.1 244.8z"/>
      </defs>
      <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
        <use xlink:href="#shade_of_paws" overflow="visible"/>
      </clipPath>
      <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)" fill="#7DBCE7" d="M200.9 199.8c0 13.9-32.2 25.1-71.9 25.1 -39.7 0-71.9-11.3-71.9-25.1 0-13.9 32.2-25.1 71.9-25.1C168.7 174.7 200.9 185.9 200.9 199.8L200.9 199.8zM200.9 199.8"/>
     <animate attributeName="opacity" values="0;1" begin="fillBody.end-3s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" /> 
     </g>
      
      
      <path id="body" fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#010101" stroke-dasharray="1533" stroke-dashoffset="1533" d="M255.8 95.6l0.2-0.9c-21.1-4.2-42.7-4.3-55.8-3.7 2.1-7.7 2.8-16.7 2.8-26.6 0-14.3-5.4-25.7-14-34.3 1.5-4.9 3.5-15.8-2-29.7 0 0-9.8-3.1-32.1 11.8 -8.7-2.2-18-3.3-27.3-3.3 -10.2 0-20.5 1.3-30.2 3.9C74.4-2.9 64.3 0.3 64.3 0.3c-6.6 16.5-2.5 28.8-1.3 31.8 -7.8 8.4-12.5 19.1-12.5 32.2 0 9.9 1.1 18.8 3.9 26.5 -13.2-0.5-34-0.3-54.4 3.8l0.2 0.9c20.4-4.1 41.4-4.2 54.5-3.7 0.6 1.6 1.3 3.2 2 4.7 -13 0.4-35.1 2.1-56.3 8.1l0.3 0.9c21.4-6 43.7-7.6 56.6-8 7.8 14.4 23 23.8 50.2 26.7 -3.9 2.6-7.8 7-9.4 14.5 -5.3 2.5-21.9 8.7-31.9-8.5 0 0-5.6-10.2-16.3-11 0 0-10.4-0.2-0.7 6.5 0 0 6.9 3.3 11.7 15.6 0 0 6.3 21 36.4 14.2V177c0 0-0.6 7.7-7.7 10.2 0 0-4.2 2.9 0.3 4.5 0 0 19.5 1.6 19.5-14.4v-23.6c0 0-0.8-9.4 3.8-12.6v38.8c0 0-0.3 9.3-5.1 12.8 0 0-3.2 5.7 3.8 4.2 0 0 13.4-1.9 14-17.6l0.3-39.3h3.2l0.3 39.3c0.6 15.6 14 17.6 14 17.6 7 1.6 3.8-4.2 3.8-4.2 -4.8-3.5-5.1-12.8-5.1-12.8v-38.5c4.6 3.6 3.8 12.3 3.8 12.3v23.6c0 16 19.5 14.4 19.5 14.4 4.5-1.6 0.3-4.5 0.3-4.5 -7-2.6-7.7-10.2-7.7-10.2v-31c0-12.1-5.1-18.5-10.1-21.8 29-2.9 42.9-12.2 49.3-26.8 12.7 0.3 35.6 1.9 57.4 8.1l0.3-0.9c-21.7-6.1-44.4-7.7-57.3-8.1 0.6-1.5 1.1-3 1.6-4.6C212.9 91.4 234.6 91.4 255.8 95.6L255.8 95.6zM255.8 95.6">
     <animate id="strBody"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="1533;0" dur="1.5s" fill="freeze" /> 
      <animate id="fillBody"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillMuzzle.end" values="#fff;#010101"  dur="5s" fill="freeze" />  
     </path>
     
     
      
      <path id="muzzle" fill="none" stroke="#F5CCB3" stroke-dasharray="298" stroke-dashoffset="298" d="M174.6 63.7c6.2 5.7 9.9 12.5 9.9 19.8 0 34.4-25.6 35.3-57.2 35.3 -31.6 0-57.2-4.8-57.2-35.3 0-7.3 3.6-14.1 9.8-19.7 10.3-9.4 27.7-4.4 47.4-4.4C147 59.4 164.3 54.3 174.6 63.7L174.6 63.7zM174.6 63.7">
      <animate id="strMuzzle"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="strBody.end" values="298;0" dur="0.8s" fill="freeze" /> 
      <animate id="fillMuzzle"  attributeName="fill" begin="strMuzzle.end" values="#fff;#F5CCB3"  dur="0.25s" fill="freeze" />
      </path>
     
     
      <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M108.3 85.3c0 9.5-5.3 17.1-11.9 17.1 -6.6 0-11.9-7.7-11.9-17.1 0-9.5 5.3-17.1 11.9-17.1C103 68.1 108.3 75.8 108.3 85.3L108.3 85.3zM108.3 85.3"/>
     
     <path  id="leftEye"fill="#fff" d="M104.5 85.5c0 6.3-3.6 11.4-7.9 11.4 -4.4 0-7.9-5.1-7.9-11.4 0-6.3 3.6-11.4 7.9-11.4C100.9 74.1 104.5 79.2 104.5 85.5L104.5 85.5zM104.5 85.5">
     <animate id="fillLeftEye"  attributeName="fill" begin="strBody.end" values="#fff;#AF5C51"  dur="1.5s" fill="freeze" />
     </path>

     <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M172.2 85.3c0 9.5-5.3 17.1-11.9 17.1 -6.6 0-11.9-7.7-11.9-17.1 0-9.5 5.3-17.1 11.9-17.1C166.8 68.1 172.2 75.8 172.2 85.3L172.2 85.3zM172.2 85.3"/>
     
      <path  id="rightEye" fill="#fff" d="M168.3 85.5c0 6.3-3.6 11.4-7.9 11.4 -4.4 0-7.9-5.1-7.9-11.4 0-6.3 3.6-11.4 7.9-11.4C164.8 74.1 168.3 79.2 168.3 85.5L168.3 85.5zM168.3 85.5">
      <animate id="fillRightEye"  attributeName="fill" begin="strBody.end" values="#fff;#AF5C51"  dur="1.5s" fill="freeze" />
     </path>
      
      <path id="nose" fill="#fff" d="M130.5 100.5c0 1.6-1.3 3-3 3 -1.6 0-3-1.3-3-3s1.3-3 3-3C129.1 97.5 130.5 98.8 130.5 100.5L130.5 100.5zM130.5 100.5">
      <animate id="fillNose"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillRightEye.end+0.5s;fillMouth.end" values="#fff;#F5CCB3;#AF5C51"  dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
     </path>
      <path id="Mouth" fill="#fff" d="M120.6 108c-0.2-0.5 0.1-1 0.6-1.2 0.5-0.2 1 0.1 1.2 0.6 0.8 2.2 2.8 3.6 5.1 3.6 2.3 0 4.3-1.5 5.1-3.6 0.2-0.5 0.7-0.8 1.2-0.6 0.5 0.2 0.8 0.7 0.6 1.2 -1 2.9-3.8 4.9-6.9 4.9C124.4 112.9 121.6 110.9 120.6 108L120.6 108zM120.6 108">
      <animate id="fillMouth"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillNose.end" values="#fff;#F5CCB3;#AF5C51"  dur="1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1" />
      </path>
      
      <path id="Dash1" fill="#fff" d="M54.5 121.6c0 0.8-0.9 1.4-2.1 1.4 -1.1 0-2.1-0.6-2.1-1.4 0-0.8 0.9-1.4 2.1-1.4C53.6 120.2 54.5 120.8 54.5 121.6L54.5 121.6zM54.5 121.6">
      <animate id="fillDash1"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillBody.end-3s" values="#fff;#C4E5D9"  dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" />
      </path>
      <path id="Dash2" fill="#fff" d="M60.3 124.8c0 0.8-0.9 1.4-2.1 1.4 -1.1 0-2.1-0.6-2.1-1.4 0-0.8 0.9-1.4 2.1-1.4C59.4 123.4 60.3 124 60.3 124.8L60.3 124.8zM60.3 124.8">
      <animate id="fillDash2"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillDash1.end" values="#fff;#C4E5D9"  dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" />
      </path>
      
      <path id="Dash3" fill="#fff" d="M63.8 129c0 0.8-0.9 1.4-2.1 1.4 -1.1 0-2.1-0.6-2.1-1.4 0-0.8 0.9-1.4 2.1-1.4C62.9 127.5 63.8 128.2 63.8 129L63.8 129zM63.8 129">
       <animate id="fillDash3"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillDash2.end" values="#fff;#C4E5D9"  dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" />
      </path>
      
      <path id="Dash4" fill="#fff" d="M67 133.8c0 0.8-0.9 1.4-2.1 1.4 -1.1 0-2.1-0.6-2.1-1.4 0-0.8 0.9-1.4 2.1-1.4C66.1 132.3 67 133 67 133.8L67 133.8zM67 133.8">
      <animate id="fillDash4"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillDash3.end" values="#fff;#C4E5D9"  dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" />
      </path>
      
      <path id="Dash5" fill="#fff" d="M70.5 138.2c0 0.8-0.9 1.4-2.1 1.4 -1.1 0-2.1-0.6-2.1-1.4 0-0.8 0.9-1.4 2.1-1.4C69.6 136.8 70.5 137.4 70.5 138.2L70.5 138.2zM70.5 138.2">
       <animate id="fillDash5"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillDash4.end" values="#fff;#C4E5D9"  dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" />
      </path> 
      
      <path id="Dash6" fill="#fff" d="M75.3 142.1c0 0.8-0.9 1.4-2.1 1.4 -1.1 0-2.1-0.6-2.1-1.4 0-0.8 0.9-1.4 2.1-1.4C74.4 140.6 75.3 141.3 75.3 142.1L75.3 142.1zM75.3 142.1">
         <animate id="fillDash6"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillDash5.end" values="#fff;#C4E5D9"  dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" />
      </path> 
      
      <path id="Dash7" fill="#fff" d="M82 144.6c0 0.8-0.9 1.4-2.1 1.4 -1.1 0-2.1-0.6-2.1-1.4 0-0.8 0.9-1.4 2.1-1.4C81.1 143.2 82 143.8 82 144.6L82 144.6zM82 144.6">
       <animate id="fillDash7"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillDash6.end" values="#fff;#C4E5D9"  dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" />
      </path> 
     
     <path id="Dash8" fill="#fff" d="M88.7 144.6c0 0.8-0.9 1.4-2.1 1.4 -1.1 0-2.1-0.6-2.1-1.4 0-0.8 0.9-1.4 2.1-1.4C87.8 143.2 88.7 143.8 88.7 144.6L88.7 144.6zM88.7 144.6"> 
        <animate id="fillDash8"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillDash7.end" values="#fff;#C4E5D9"  dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" />
      </path> 
     
     
      <path id="Dash9" fill="#fff" d="M95.5 143.5c0 0.8-0.9 1.4-2.1 1.4 -1.1 0-2.1-0.6-2.1-1.4 0-0.8 0.9-1.4 2.1-1.4C94.5 142.1 95.5 142.7 95.5 143.5L95.5 143.5zM95.5 143.5"> 
          <animate id="fillDash9"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillDash8.end" values="#fff;#C4E5D9"  dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" />
      </path> 
      
      <path id="droplet" fill="#fff" d="M46.9 125.9l-2.1 7.2c0 0-0.5 2.6 1.9 3.1 2.6-0.1 2.4-2.5 2.2-3.2L46.9 125.9 46.9 125.9zM46.9 125.9">  
      
       <animate id="fillDash10"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillDash9.end" values="#fff;#C4E5D9"  dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" />
      </path>  
   
   <circle id="crc1" cx="128" cy="94" r="128" fill="none" opacity="0" stroke="#A0544A" stroke-width="25" stroke-dasharray="30 8.192" >
        <animate
        id="an_body"
     attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
     begin="an_opacity.end"
     dur="7s"
     values="803.84;0"
     fill="freeze"
     repeatCount="indefinite" />   
   </circle>  
   
       <animate
        id="an_opacity"
     xlink:href="#crc1"
     attributeName="opacity"
     begin="fillRightEye.end"
     dur="3s"
     values="0;1"
     fill="freeze"
     />   
   
   
</svg>
```